# IOS prepareForSegue pass a data successfully but viewdidload clear it?

Tags: ios, uiviewcontroller

In UIViewController A I performSegue to UIViewControllerB.And  in the prepaerForSegue function of A, I use set function set a strong variable 's value of B. However, when the B's viewDidLoad()  called, the value is nil.
Anybody help me and tell me why?

my code is:

```
UIViewController A:

- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
     CXPWDViewController *cxpwdViewController=[[CXPWDViewController alloc] init];
     //I can't use the segue.desinationViewController, cause it is a present modally , the desinationViewController is         navigationViewController.
     [cxpwdViewController setAction:@"EnterPasscode"];//here the cxpwdViewController .action is @"EnterPasscode"
}

UIViewController B:

-(void) viewDidLoad()
{
[super viewDidLoad];// here the cxpwdViewController .action is nil; Why?
}
```

Comment: It does not matter what type of navigation is. Just use segue.destinationviewcontroller. It will work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are presenting an `UINavigationViewController`, then the `rootViewController` controller should be your `CXPWDViewController`. So that you can typeacast the same. Since you are creating an anaother viewcontroller instance you are not getting the value.Try this code.

UIViewController A:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
 {
     if([[segue destinationViewController] isKindOfClass:[UINavigationViewController class]])
      {
        UINavigationViewController* destinationNavController =(NavigationViewController*)[segue destinationViewController]; 
        CXPWDViewController *cxpwdViewController=(CXPWDViewController*)[destinationNavController.viewControllers firstObject];
        if([cxpwdViewController isKindOfClass:[CXPWDViewController class]])
        {
            [cxpwdViewController setAction:@"EnterPasscode"];
        }  
    } 
}
```

Comment: Thank you. I know the reason, but your code does not work for me, I don't find the rootViewContoller selector of navigationController, but I get the navigationController.viewControllers array . And I guess the array[0] is the root. Am I right? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

```
 CXPWDViewController *cxpwdViewController=[[CXPWDViewController alloc] init];
 //I can't use the segue.desinationViewController
```

I don't know why you think you can't use the segue destination view controller. But in any case you *certainly* can't do what you want to do *this* way. You are creating a completely *different* CXPWDViewController - and then destroying it an instant later. You won't get far that way!

Comment: Yeah, when I debug the code , I know the object address is different, but ignore it . Your answer is right and I create a new instant and destroyed later. Thanks for your help.